# "No route to host" from my laptop while connected at home, while using SOCKS proxy or another computer work fine

Tags: macos, networking, troubleshooting, routing

This has been baffling me for some time. A single domain (haxe.org) is inaccessible from my laptop (OSX 10.7.5) while connected via my home network. Attempting to ping it results in "No route to host" and "Host is down" messages.

Thinking it was an issue with my ISP / connection in general, I set up an SSH tunnel to my work to use as a SOCKS proxy. With this in place I can browse the site in chrome and other SOCKS aware applications. Unfortunately this workaround isn't sufficient as the haxelib commandline tool I'm trying to use doesn't do SOCKS. Being the first thing I tried when others told me the site was still up, I assumed this isolated the issue to my Internet connection.

In a stroke of inspiration this morning, I attempted to browse the site using an iPad. Lo and behold, it works! But from the laptop, still nothing. The iPad is connected to the same network (both over wifi), can browse the site with no issue.

My fault is at the same not with my laptop, and not with my network. At this point I fear the solution may be painfully obvious, but after staring at this problem for days I cannot see it.

Any and all suggestions are welcome.

PS: The domain is resolving correctly to 5.39.76.185 regardless of tunnelled vs direct connection. Both the iPad and laptop are set to use my router for DNS and it is set to my ISP's recommended IPs. (Before troubleshooting, it was set to OpenDNS servers)

**[UPDATE]**

As per user3050461's suggestion, I've included the output of `route` below. I believe we've found our culprit, but WHY? What's a `ham0` interface, and who the heck is monreseau.home ("mynetwork.home" in french)??

From home

```
> route get google.com
   route to: yyz08s13-in-f3.1e100.net
destination: default
       mask: default
    gateway: monreseau.home
  interface: en1
      flags: <UP,GATEWAY,DONE,STATIC,PRCLONING>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500         0 

> route get haxe.org
   route to: ks3261879.kimsufi.com
destination: 5.0.0.0
       mask: 255.0.0.0
  interface: ham0
      flags: <UP,DONE,CLONING>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1200    -60647
```

From work

```
> route get haxe.org
   route to: ks3261879.kimsufi.com
destination: default
       mask: default
    gateway: gw-113
  interface: en0
      flags: <UP,GATEWAY,DONE,STATIC,PRCLONING>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500         0
```

[UPDATE 2]

What is `ham0` and why is it stealing (is it?) every address that starts with 5 (haxe.org's 5.39.76.185 included)? What is the syntax to delete this from my routing table?

```
> netstat -nr
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.2.1        UGSc           33       13     en1
5                  link#8             UC              2        0    ham0
5.255.255.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        2    ham0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             15   101400     lo0
127.94.0.1         127.94.0.1         UH              0        0     lo0
127.94.0.2         127.94.0.2         UH              0        0     lo0
169.254            link#5             UCS             0        0     en1
192.168.2          link#5             UCS             3        0     en1
192.168.2.1        68:15:90:40:2b:40  UHLWIi         49     4454     en1   1192
192.168.2.10       127.0.0.1          UHS             0        0     lo0
192.168.2.11       d4:4b:5e:c4:7b:e2  UHLWIi          0        0     en1    598
192.168.2.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0       10     en1

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
::1                                     link#1                          UHL             lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en0/64                           link#4                          UCI             en0
fe80::%en1/64                           link#5                          UCI             en1
fe80::daa2:5eff:fe8f:4ace%en1           d8:a2:5e:8f:4a:ce               UHLI            lo0
ff01::%lo0/32                           fe80::1%lo0                     UmCI            lo0
ff01::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff01::%en1/32                           link#5                          UmCI            en1
ff02::%lo0/32                           fe80::1%lo0                     UmCI            lo0
ff02::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff02::%en1/32                           link#5                          UmCI            en1
```

Comment: Only two things I could think of would be a firewall setting on the laptop, or a firewall setting on the router blocking that site's IP from your laptop's IP.  Maybe try temporarily disabling the Mac OS X firewall, and/or try changing the IP address of your laptop on your LAN?

Comment: OSX firewall is disabled, and I don't think my router has one (Sagemcom F@st 2864 running Bell Connection Hub).

I tried connecting my laptop using ethernet, which uses a different MAC address and was granted a new IP, but still nothing.

Comment: When you see "No route to host", does it say where that message is coming from? I would also try running `traceroute haxe.org` and `route` to see if they offer any clues as to where the failure is.

Comment: are you located in Canada? this monreseau.home thing seems to be from Bell Canada.

Comment: Its a dupe! http://superuser.com/questions/461825/cannot-access-pear-php-net-from-osx-lion Damn you hamachi!